# Matlab exits during installation without any prompt or error hint

Tags: matlab

I was installing matlab 2021b using the online installer. At first, everything went well and it began the installation process. But at some point, when the progress bar is at 15%, 40% or so, it exits without any warning or error report. I've tried several times but it just won't work. What do I do now?

Comment: Can you download an offline installer and then run  that?

Comment: How do I download an offline installer? I don't know.

Comment: [How can I get MATLAB installation files for use on an offline machine? - MATLAB Answers - MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/259632-how-can-i-get-matlab-installation-files-for-use-on-an-offline-machine)

Comment: OMG, even download without install, it still exits......

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with your internet...